# square or Image icon pulling in the List in Paginated Reports

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, dax, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have not added any image to the list, but when viewing the Paginated Report in Power BI Report Server I can see a broken image link.

Can anyone help me understand the reason why the icon has been showing up and help me get rid of it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the Simplest Solution that I found was to not use Line.

I was using Line for the formatting purpose and it was mentioned in some article that in older version of report viewer, it  search for padding and calls a blank image.

So I replaced Line with Textboxes with making the Top of the Textbox solid. This resolved my issue.